# make install tries to copy a file twice

Tags: makefile, heartbeat, make-install

I'm trying to build a package from source. The `./configure` and `make` steps work out, but `sudo make install` or `sudo checkinstall` results in an error:

[image]

As we can see *drbd* is listed twice in the `/usr/bin/install -c` line.

The problem is I don't really know how to go about this. As expected, this list of files (ha resource agents) is not present in any of the Makefiles or install-sh, but generated somehow on the go.

Any ideas of where to look for or how to remove duplicate entry from this list? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I was mistaken and the above list was present in one of *Makefile.am* files. Here is the [post](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=54364&start=0#p369604) that helped me out:

> This issue is caused because for those earlier versions we incorrectly
>   had those specified files listed twice in the Makefile.am and with the
>   newer Automake versions this causes the errors you received.

p.s. Sorry, it was a haste to ask the question. Let this thread be for reference in that case.